# Unique values in Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize ORM for Node.js. I need to get lines with unique values in certain column. Example table:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
1  | One  | 2
2  | Two  | 1
3  | Three| 2
4  | Four | 3
5  | Five | 1
```

Query for column `group` and result:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
1  | One  | 2
2  | Two  | 1
4  | Four | 3
```

Lines One, Two and Four was the first who had unique `group` values. How to make it in Sequelize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Sequelize raw query is one way of getting out the rows that you want:

```
/*
  var sql =
    SELECT r.id,
         r.name,
         r.groupnum
    FROM s04.row r
    JOIN
      (SELECT min(id) AS id,
              groupnum
       FROM s04.row
       GROUP BY groupnum) s 
    ON r.id = s.id
*/
return sq.query(sql, { type: sq.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

The resulting promise will resolve to a JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "One",
    "groupnum": 2
  }
  ...
]
```

If you then needed to work with these rows as Instances you can call `build` on each element of the array:

```
Model.build({ /* attributes-hash */ }, { isNewRecord: false })
```

See [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/04-unique-values) for an example. If I find a way of doing this via Sequelize function calls (`aggregate`, `find*`, etc) that isn't too hideous I'll also post that here as a separate answer.